# Two React states are not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

Whenever i hit my sign in button with empty email and password fields, my code should update my emailError state and passwordError with Some message but it is only updating passwordError state.

```
const validateSignIn = () => {
    let errorCount = 0;
    const emailExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/
    const Passwordexp = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/

    const validEmail = emailExp.test(loginDetails.email)
    const validPassword = Passwordexp.test(loginDetails.password)
    console.log(validEmail, validPassword)
    console.log(loginDetails)
    if (loginDetails.email == "") {
      setLoginDetails({ ...loginDetails, emailError: "Email cannot be left empty"})
      errorCount = errorCount + 1
    }
    else if (validEmail == false) {
      setLoginDetails({ ...loginDetails, emailError : "Invalid email address"})
      errorCount = errorCount + 1
    }

    if (loginDetails.password == "") {
      setLoginDetails({ ...loginDetails, passwordError: "Password field cannot be left Empty" })
      errorCount = errorCount + 1
    }
    else if (validPassword == false) {
      setLoginDetails({ ...loginDetails,passwordError: "Invalid Password" })
      errorCount = errorCount + 1
    }

    if (errorCount == 0) {
          navigation.replace('dashboard')
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that each enqueued update is updating from the same stale `loginDetails` state that's closed over in callback scope. The last update processed is the one that is set and available on the next render.

Use [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) if enqueueing multiple updates to the same state in the same function scope. The allows updating from the previous state value instead of the value closed over in scope.

```
const validateSignIn = () => {
  let errorCount = 0;
  const emailExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/;
  const Passwordexp = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/;

  const validEmail = emailExp.test(loginDetails.email);
  const validPassword = Passwordexp.test(loginDetails.password);
  console.log(validEmail, validPassword);
  console.log(loginDetails);
  if (loginDetails.email == "") {
    setLoginDetails((loginDetails) => ({ // <-- function is passed previous state
      ...loginDetails,
      emailError: "Email cannot be left empty"
    }));
    errorCount = errorCount + 1;
  } else if (validEmail == false) {
    setLoginDetails((loginDetails) => ({
      ...loginDetails,
      emailError: "Invalid email address"
    }));
    errorCount = errorCount + 1;
  }

  if (loginDetails.password == "") {
    setLoginDetails((loginDetails) => ({
      ...loginDetails,
      passwordError: "Password field cannot be left Empty"
    }));
    errorCount = errorCount + 1;
  } else if (validPassword == false) {
    setLoginDetails((loginDetails) => ({
      ...loginDetails,
      passwordError: "Invalid Password"
    }));
    errorCount = errorCount + 1;
  }

  if (errorCount == 0) {
    navigation.replace("dashboard");
  }
};
```

A suggested improvement would be to create a local `errors` object and set error properties on it, then either enqueue a single state update or navigate.

```
const validateSignIn = () => {
  const errors = {};

  const emailExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/;
  const Passwordexp = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/;

  const validEmail = emailExp.test(loginDetails.email);
  const validPassword = Passwordexp.test(loginDetails.password);

  if (!loginDetails.email) {
    errors.emailError = "Email cannot be left empty";
  } else if (!validEmail) {
    errors.emailError = "Invalid email address";
  }

  if (!loginDetails.password) {
    errors.passwordError = "Password field cannot be left Empty";
  } else if (!validPassword) {
    errors.passwordError = "Invalid Password";
  }

  if (Object.values(errors).length) {
    setLoginDetails(loginDetails => ({
      ...loginDetails,
      ...errors,
    }))
  } else {
    navigation.replace("dashboard");
  }
};
```